# Converting datetime type to hex value prints wrong answer

Tags: c#, hex

i'm working with c#. I'm trying to convert my variable date1 which type is system.datetime to hex value. According to converters online, it's value should be **0000015908178fd8**. I was surfing the internet and found that I can convert datetime to hex by using ticks function. However I'm getting this output **8D425D2D3A13580**. I guess there is flaw in my logic or somekind of misunderstanding. What I'm doing wrong?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2016, 12, 16, 16, 44, 39);
       Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString()); // output 16.12.2016 16:44:39

       Console.WriteLine(date1.Ticks.ToString("X2")); // output 8D425D2D3A13580
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried first using the conversion on a small value that you know the hex value of? Plus, don't assume that online converters are correct ;)

Comment: Are online converters *convert* [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) as you do? From msdn:  *A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second. The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar)*

Comment: What exactly did you convert in the online coverter? The string of the datetime won't be the same as the ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (but count *milliseconds*, not *seconds*):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2016, 12, 16, 16, 44, 39);

string result = 
  ((long)(date1 - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds).ToString("x");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
15908856cd8
```

Answer (score 1):

Your converter represents date time as "milliseconds which passed since January 1st 1970", like time is represented in javascript. So to achieve the same result in C# you have to do:

```
var date1 = new System.DateTime(2016, 12, 16, 16, 44, 39);
var timestamp = (long) (date1.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(timestamp.ToString("X2"));
// outputs 1590772C458
```

Note that output depends on your current timezone, because `date1` will be assumed as time in your local timezone in this case.